# MongoDB: update a certain nested element in all documents (that may not have that element's parent)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So, I have a collection of player objects that look something like:

```
scriptData: {
    gameState: {
        heroRoster: {
            hero1: {
                abilityTrees: [{
                    handle: 'conjuration',
                    abilities: {
                        // ...
                    }
                }]
            },
            hero2: {
                abilityTrees: [{
                    handle: 'movement',
                    abilities: {
                        stance_dancing: {
                            passive: true
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and I'm trying to run an update() query that will set `stance_dancing.passive` to `false` for every hero that has that ability tree, for every player object in the collection.

As you can see, tho, not every hero has the 'movement' ability tree. Any tips what this query is supposed to look like?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO you will have to do it in javascript

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have all your hero's in a collection of hero's :)
you can update with:

Find :

```
{ "abilityTrees.abilities.stance_dancing.passive": { $exists: true } }
```

Update :

```
{
    $set: {
        "abilityTrees.$.abilities.stance_dancing.passive" : false 
    }
}
```

This finds all documents where the "abilityTrees.abilities.stance_dancing.passive" exists and set's the passive field to the specified value